# Unable to get out of loops

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I'm trying to write a MasterMind game using classes and objects and I'm currently stuck around some of my loops.

```
while True:
# create a combination
# test the combination
while game_won == False:
    print(scoreboard)
    # player input combination
    # combination is tested then added to scoreboard
    tries_left = tries_left+1
    if game_won == True:
        print(You Won!)
        input = Play Again? Y/N
    if tries_left == 10:
        print(You Lost!)
        input = Play Again? Y/N
```

How do I do to go back to my while True -> create combination from my last if statement? (if tries_left == 10:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What's wrong

- Your first `while True` doesn't have anything in it, You need to indent code under it if you want it to be inside the loop.
- There is a few typos, missing comment characters, and quotation marks.

### What needs to happen

- When the nested while loop `while game_won == True` exits, the code will return looping the parent loop `while True`, which will replay the game, if the user wishes.

### Your code fixed (with a few improvements)

Following is how you can loop the game forever (given the user wishes it).

```
# Assume user wants to play when the program runs
user_wants_to_play = True
ans = ""

# loop the entire game while the user wishes to play
while user_wants_to_play:
    # Create the combination
    # Test the combination

    # Game isn't done when started
    game_done = False
    tries_left = 10  # Arbitrary number I chose

    while not game_done:
        # Play the game
        print("Scoreboard")

        # Subtract one to tries left
        tries_left -= 1

        if game_done:
            print("You won!")

        elif tries_left == 0:
            print("You lost!")
            game_done = True

        # if users answer was 'n'
    ans = input("Play again? Y/N \n")
    if ans.strip().upper() == 'N':
        user_wants_to_play = False
```

#### Improvements

- Boolean logic is more pythonic using `not` instead of `myBool == False`
- `while True:` changed to `while user_wants_to_play:`
- User input is scrubbed to ignore white-space and lower case
- Changed `game_won` to `game_done`
- Made `tries_left` count down instead

Comment: Thank you sir for your great explanation!